# Locally install solution for Surveys, Newsletter and Events

Tags: events, sharepoint

At work asked me to find a solution locally installable in `Sharepoint` to allow use of surveys, newsletter and events.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

All of these items are available within SharePoint Out-Of-The-Box (OOTB).  The instructions depend on the version of SharePoint you are running.

You can create a survey by adding a survey to your site.

[SharePoint 2010 steps](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-a-survey-76e32bcc-5638-4f99-9585-d770d348ee16)

[SharePoint 2013 steps](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-survey-ea52a787-822e-4f7e-b5ed-77bb14df3aba)

An announcements list will likely work for you as a newsletter as it can post announcements and important items (with the ability to expire the items)

[SharePoint 2010 Announcement List](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/iersoy/how-to-create-and-manage-announcement-in-sharepoint-2010/)

[SharePoint 2013 Announcement List](http://www.portalintegrators.com/how-to-create-announcements-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Events can be handled by the Calendar List

[SharePoint 2010 Calendar List](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-or-delete-a-list-0d397414-d95f-41eb-addd-5e6eff41b083#__toc239839008)

[SharePoint 2013 Calendar List](http://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-calendar-and-add-an-event)

Hope this helps!